# Problema con variable en ruta

Tags: python

Estimadxs buenas tardes, estoy iniciándome en el mundo python. Estoy creando un script para búsqueda de grabaciones, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero al querer listar archivos con un patrón que busca extensiones .WAV, y en el mismo nombre del archivo no puedo lograr que busque la fecha con una variable antes declarada. Dejo el código a ver si algun@ puede darme una mano.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
fecha = date.strftime('%Y''%m''%d')
 
directorio = (os.path.join)(str(src), '*[in, out]-*-*[201228, 201614, 201241, 201514, 201504, 201621, 201574, 201628, 201695, 201634, 201633, 201571, 201638, 201573, 201632, 201530, 201629, 201629, 201526, 201662, 1228, 1614, 1241, 1514, 1504, 1621, 1574, 1628, 1695, 1634, 1633, 1571, 1638, 1573, 1632, 1530, 1629, 1526, 1662 ]-*', str(fecha),'*.wav')"

######### Busqueda de grabaciones ##############
def listar_archivos(ruta):
    listar_audios = glob(ruta)
    return listar_audios
input = listar_archivos(directorio)
for f in input:
    print(f)
#### Copiado de audios #### FUNCIONA!
audios = glob(directorio)
for name in audios:
    shutil.copy(name, nombre_carpeta3)`
```

Comment: Si tienes la fecha actual con el formato`'%Y %m %d`, puedes declararlo :`fecha = str(date.strftime('%Y %m %d'))` y luego para obtener los archivos cuyos nombres contengan esa fecha y la extensión que deseas: `targetPattern = r"directorio\*"+fecha+"*.wav"`

Comment: Buenas tardes @Firefly, desde ya gracias por la respuesta. Pero al declararlo me trae todos los archivos no los filtrados por el str de 'fecha'.
pad = r"directorio\*"+fecha+"*.wav"

Comment: Acá lo probé ayer con este código: `import glob
from datetime import date
date=date.today()
fecha = str(date.strftime('%Y %m %d'))

targetPattern = r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Directorio\*"+fecha+"*.wav"
print(glob.glob(targetPattern))`. En `Directorio` habían archivos con diferentes extensiones, entre ellos .wav y algunos tenían en su nombre la fecha `2021 09 29` y sólo me imprimió en consola los nombres de los archivos que tenían esa fecha en alguna parte de su nombre y con esa extensión.

Comment: Me funciono correctamente, muchas gracias Firefly!!!